# Why did the US Military not assist in the Wakanda battle during Avengers: Infinity War

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Looking for a strictly in universe answer, as the out of universe answer is obvious.

A squadron of fighter jets (from any country for that matter) would have seemed to be more affect than most of the avengers that were on screen fighting.

I know shield might normally handle that type of thing, but that doesn't mean the US wouldn't get involved also.  General Ross was there so the US seemed to have been briefed on the situation, and they had a CIA operative in Wakanda, so it doesn't seem to be due to lack of knowledge.

Was it something to do with the outcome of civil war?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few reasons I can see why the US military didn't/couldn't help during Wakanda battles.

At the end of the Civil War, everyone was a wanted criminal or had disobeyed the US Government. So, why would US military assist them? In *Infinity War*, the following conversation goes on between Cap and the secretary.

> **Secretary:** The world's on fire. And you think, all is forgiven?
>
> **Captain America:** I am not looking for forgiveness. And I am way past asking for permission. Earth just lost her best defender. So, we're here to fight. And if you wanna stand in our way, we'll fight you too.

Rhodes was the only person left who could ask for assistance, but he also throws it away by declining order from Secretary about arresting Captain and others.

> **Rhodes:** That's a court-martial.

If you remember, they went to Wakanda to remove the Mind Stone from Vision. They knew that Thanos is coming to get the stone, but no one knew that he will send the Black Order with an army to retrieve it.

The war started all of a sudden in a nation where US military is not present at all. There was no time to call for the military assistance. And during the battle, Thor showed up. After which, they hardly needed any military assistance.

Comment: And then they lost.

Comment: The fate of half the population of the universe was at stake. Would the US be so foolish as to not try and help with those stakes? That's what I don't get.

Comment: @JakeRankin The fact is the US military didn't know that it's Thanos coming to wipe out half the population. IIRC, Bruce told Strange and Stark about it who apparently left Earth and he didn't tell this to rest.

Comment: Didn't the space ship appearing in the village kind of tick them of?

Comment: Notably, unlike the Avengers, the U.S. military doesn't have the technology to travel halfway across the planet in a matter of minutes. They're also no longer getting any weapons tech from Stark (after the events of Iron Man I) or from his rival Justin Hammer (after the events of Iron Man II) and no longer have the support of SHIELD (after Captain America: Winter Soldier).

Comment: That's where you're wrong. The US Marines are on constant patrol on 3 distinct areas of the world: Atlantic, Pacific, and Asia. US Marines can deploy a sizeable force, armor, artillery, heavy weapons, with fixed and rotary wing support, to secure a foothold anywhere in the world within a very short period. They don't have to 'get halfway across the world' - they're already within range of anywhere in the world. And that's just the Marines - the US Army have the same capabilities via airdrop. The only caveat is that forces are closer to hotspots versus non-perceived threat areas.

Comment: Furthermore, the very scene you call out with the defense secretary indicates that the US DoD was closely monitoring the situation, and even if we assume some movie-magic lightspeed into the atmosphere sort of stuff, the US DoD would have been alerted the moment they showed up. Fighters would have been available almost immediately. I can tell you that the US Marines IRL have a base only about 650 miles from fictional Wakanda, that surely can scramble FA/18s from, with refueling support can reach Wakanda fast enough to help before the end of the battle.

Comment: And that's, of course, excluding presences that I don't know about. I call out the Marine base because I know of it, but I'm sure there are others nearby as well. Maybe even some IRL Kenya I'm sure, which would be far closer than the one I know of for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Wakanda, as you saw when the heroes flew into it, was still being hidden by their illusion field.  The US military wasn't even necessarily sufficiently aware of what was going on, not to mention, there was no depiction of anyone asking for the US military to help in that particular battle.

Other than that, up to and including Avengers Infinity War, there was no specific explanation given for this situation.